# Use "requests" python library when ca_bundle is available as a string

Tags: python

Requirement is to create a Python object that can do HTTP requests for endpoints with both public and private CAs.

This is not possible today as requests library's API doesn't accept ca_bundle as a string, but as a path on disk.

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.google.com", verify="/path/to/bundle")
```

This poses a problem if my ca_bundle in question is a collection of multiple files. One way is to create a temporary file and pass that as a `verify=` parameter, but I don't think of that as an elegant way.

After some research, I learnt that `requests` library uses `urllib3` under the hood. In my mind, I can read the multiple bundles as string and then somehow pass that to the requests library objects. There are multiple options that I thought about:-

- Configure the underlying attribute `ca_cert_data` of `urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection`.
- Create a custom `urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool` object as it accepts `**conn_kw`, which has one of the parameters as `ca_cert_data`.

There could be more ways, but I'm unable to think clearly on how to correctly use the requests API.

Comment: ...what's wrong with using a temporary file context manager? It's secure, the file is readable and writable only by the creating user id. Seems easiest to me.